# Converting disjunctive inequality to absolute value

Tags: inequality

I want to use Chebyshev's inequality to calculate the an upper bound on the probability that X lies outside the range $[6, 14]$.

X has mean $\mu = 10$.

So I must find  $\alpha$ such that $\vert X - 10 \vert \geq \alpha$.

I also know that $X < 6 \lor X > 14$.

How can I solve for $\alpha$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Think of $\mu = 10$ as the "centre" or midpoint of the interval, and think of $\alpha$ as the "radius" or half the width of the interval.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what are $|6 - 10|$ and $|14 - 10|$?